# dropdown_search asyncItems doesn't work, doesn't call the function inside it

Tags: flutter, asynchronous, search, dropdown

I've been trying to implement a search from the API to the `dropdownSearch`, but the `asyncItems` doesn't call the function back.

This is the actual code that I've been trying to implement:

```
DropdownSearch<Cliente>(
                popupProps: const PopupProps.menu(
                  isFilterOnline: true,
                  showSelectedItems: true,
                  interceptCallBacks: true,
                  showSearchBox: true,
                  searchDelay: Duration(seconds: 1),
                ),
                dropdownDecoratorProps: const DropDownDecoratorProps(
                  dropdownSearchDecoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Cliente",
                    hintText: "Seleccione un cliente",
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                ),
                asyncItems: (String term) async {
                  print('Searching for $term');
                  return search.searchClients(term);
                },
                onChanged: (Cliente? cliente) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedClient = cliente;
                    if (selectedClient != null) {
                      nameController.text = selectedClient!.nombre;
                      nitController.text = selectedClient!.nit ?? 'Sin NIT';
                      ciController.text = selectedClient!.ci ?? 'Sin CI';
                    }
                  });
                },
                selectedItem: selectedClient,
                itemAsString: (Cliente u) =>
                    'Nombre: ${u.nombre}- NIT: ${u.nit} - CI: ${u.ci}',
                compareFn: (Cliente a, Cliente b) => a.nombre == b.nombre,
              ),
```

and this is how I manage the provider for this function.

```
Future<List<Cliente>> searchClients(String term) async {
    try {
      final resp = await BackendApi.search('/clientes/buscar', {'term': term});

      final clientsResp = ClientsResponse.fromMap(resp);

      clientes = [...clientsResp.clientes];

      notifyListeners();
      return clientes;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Ocurrió un error al buscar los clientes: $e');
      return [];
    }
  }
```

I want it to update using the value term, the searchbox seems to not have any connection with it.